# Referencing different objects in a class depending on user input

Tags: javascript, class, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to create a very basic physics simulation in p5.js and I am using a class to create multiple instances of the shapes (which are currently all circles), I have a function that checks if the user clicks inside the area of a circle and if so allows them to drag it around but I ran into a problem. I need to have the program work out which object it is hovering but I'm not sure how I would do so, below I have the function working for only the first object (obj1). can I do something like {classname}.posX instead?

```
function whilePressed()
    {
      if (Math.pow(mouseX-obj1.posX,2)+(Math.pow(mouseY-obj1.posY,2))<=(Math.pow(obj1.size/2,2)) | grabbed == true)
        {
          grabbed = true;
          if (firstGrab == true)
          {
            difX = (obj1.posX-mouseX);
            difY = (obj1.posY-mouseY);
            firstGrab = false;
          }
          obj1.posX = mouseX+difX;
          obj1.posY = mouseY+difY;
        }
    }
```

below is the class (the draw function has a switch statement in it because I used to have a square as well but decided to get a circle working before implementing a square)

```
class primitive
{
  constructor()
  {
    this.size = 50;
    this.posX = canvasSize/2;
    this.posY = canvasSize/2;
    this.velX = 0;
    this.velY = 0;
    this.terminalVel = 15;
  }
  
  pos(x,y)
  {
    this.posX = x;
    this.posY = y;
  }
  
  draw(shape = 'circle')
  {
    stroke(168,198,159);
    fill(204,226,163);
    switch (shape)
    {
      case 'circle':
        circle(this.posX,this.posY,this.size);
      break;
    }
  }
  
  gravity()
  {
    if (this.velY < this.terminalVel)
    {
      this.velY = (this.velY+1);  
    }
    else
    {
      this.velY = 20;
    }
    this.posY = this.posY+this.velY;
    
    if (this.posY > groundLevel-(this.size/2))
    {
      this.posY = groundLevel-(this.size/2);
      this.velY = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For anyone making an answer, I just noticed that the X and Y coordinates can change, and that means you won't store the right X and Y coordinates. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a static method on the primitive class like so:
First, create an array which has all the instances of the class in it.
This is the code:
**Remember:** I added the parameter `name` to the constructor. That means when creating an instance do it like so:

```js
var foo = new primitive("foo");
```

```js
var PRIMITIVES = [];
// ...
constructor(name)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.size = 50;
    this.posX = canvasSize/2;
    this.posY = canvasSize/2;
    this.velX = 0;
    this.velY = 0;
    this.terminalVel = 15;
    PRIMITIVES.push(name);
  }
```

Now, using the same mouse find principle, you can create a static method that finds and return the right instance.

```js
static findInstance(mouseX, mouseY) {
  for (var i = 0; i < PRIMITIVES.length; i++) 
    {
      obj = window[PRIMITIVES[i]];
      if (Math.pow(mouseX-obj.posX,2)+(Math.pow(mouseY-obj.posY,2))<=(Math.pow(obj.size/2,2)))
        {
          return obj;
        }
    }
  
}
```

Then, you can call `primitive.findInstance(mouseX, mouseY)`, and it will return the right instance. If this doesn't work, please comment. I hope this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of objects:

```js
let objects = []
```

```js
objects.push(obj1);
objects.push(obj2);
```

Implement an algorithm in the [`mousePressed()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mousePressed) callback that detects the clicked object:

```js
let draggedObject;
let dragOffsetX;
let dragOffsetY;
```

```js
function mousePressed() {
 
    draggedObject = null;

    for (let i=0; i < objects.lenght; i++) {

        obj = objects[i];
        if (Math.pow(mouseX-obj.posX,2) + Math.pow(mouseY-obj.posY,2) <= Math.pow(obj.size/2,2)) {
            
            draggedObject = obj;
            dragOffsetX = draggedObject.posX - mouseX;
            dragOffsetY = draggedObject.posY - mouseY;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Change the position of the object in the [`mouseDragged()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseDragged) callback:

```js
function mouseDragged() {

    if (dragged_object) {
        draggedObject.posX = mouseX + dragOffsetX;
        draggedObject.posY = mouseY + dragOffsetY;
    }
}
```